# Can I publish a version older than the newest on NuGet?

Tags: nuget

Suppose I have version 1.1.0 on a NuGet server.

I then continue development and push version 1.2.0.

Then I find a bug in version 1.1.0 and want to fix this.

At this point, can I still push version 1.1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in the NuGet spec or protocol that prevents it, so it might depend on which NuGet server you're using, but I would be extremely surprised if any server forbids it because it would be so short sighted, in my opinion.

Using [`NuGet.Protocol` on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Protocol/) as an example, version 4.9.3 was release in January 2019, but versions 4.8.2, 4.7.2, 4.6.3, 4.5.2, 4.4.2 and 4.3.1 were released in March, two months later.